# Available RecordStore size

Tags: java, java-me, recordstore

How can I get the total ROM memory size available for `Recordstore` in a midlet ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating an empty record store and using the methods RecordStore.getSizeAvailable() and RecordStore.getSize() to determine the total maximum size of a single record store. From experience most devices don't put a restriction on the number of record stores your application can create.