# How many records can a recordstore contain?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to know what is the maximum number of records that a recordstore can contain ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792074/available-recordstore-size

Comment: @Joachim Rohde : make it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again as an answer so the topic can be marked as solved: [Available RecordStore size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792074/available-recordstore-size)

(PS: how much do you have to write that SO does not convert your answer automatically to a comment.)

Comment: This should *not* be an answer. Instead this question should be closed as an exact duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Should I delete the answer then again? Or what should I do now?

Comment: It's not a big problem, do as you wish. I just wanted to inform you for the future. You can't yet vote to close (you need more rep for that), so a comment is usually the best thing you can do in this situation (exactly as you did!).